# IN clause not working within subquery inner join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to pull a list of *most recent lab values in 2015*. All lab value are stored in one table and I need to both limit the data to be within 2015 and limit it to certain types of labs so the max date doesn't give me the most recent lab regardless of type. Although I use the IN clause, labs of other types are included.

I need the last value regardless of what type of lab they have as long as it's within the types identified in the IN clause (i.e. I don't need the last value of each type)

```
select distinct 
    t2.pat_id
    ,t2.pat_last_name "PatientLast"
    ,t2.pat_first_name "PatFirst"
    ,t2.birth_date
    ,t1.contact_date "ContactDate"
    ,t3.name "EncounterType"
    ,t4.ord_num_value "Numeric Value"
    ,t4.result_date
 from table1 t1
 inner join table2 t2 on t1.pat_id = t2.pat_id
 inner join table3  t3 on t1.enc_type_c = t3.disp_enc_type_c
 inner join table4 t4 on t1.pat_enc_csn_id = t4.pat_enc_csn_id
 inner join 
 (
    select 
        table1.pat_id
        ,max(table1.contact_date) as LastResult
        ,table4.component_id
    from table1 
    **inner join order_results on table1.pat_enc_csn_id = table4.pat_enc_csn_id
    where table4.component_id in ('1526664','1558024','1004','2667', '1230000002','1564041') 
        and table1.contact_date between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31'
    group by table1.pat_id, table4.component_id
 ) enc2** on table1.pat_id = enc2.pat_id 
    and table1.contact_date = enc2.LastResult 
order by table2.pat_last_name, table2.pat_first_name
```

Comment: I don't get what is the real problem. As described, you can filter by date, apply `group by` on lab and obtain `max(concact_date)`  per each lab in period specified in `where` clause. Which part doesn't work? If you are needing max date _regardless_ `component_id` - remove it from `group by` and `select` but keep it in `where` clause.

Comment: I need max date of only those labs that have those component IDs, but the IN clause is failing and labs of other component types are resulting

Comment: Sorry I thought you need opposite result. Pull `component_id` out of subquery and use it in join `) enc2 on table1.pat_id = enc2.pat_id and table4.component_id = enc2.component_id`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not following. A completely separate join?

Comment: This is your join to subquery which has alias `enc2`. You already have this join but as I assume `component_id` is missing in it.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a bit hard to follow.  But one method is to use `row_number()`.  Something like this:

```
select t.*
from (select . . .,
             row_number() over (partition by pat_id order by contact_date desc) as seqnum
      from . . .
      where . . .
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You have `where` conditions in the subquery that are not in the outer query, so it is hard to follow the intended logic.  The use of `row_number()` is much simpler than a subquery, because you don't have to repeat any logic.